# iphone dev make "Developer Rejected" status for new app version.?

Tags: iphone

I have already uploaded an app with inapp products, it has been accepted and ready for sale. Now i want to add a new verison of my app with new products. So how should i add my new products? Should i have to upload n reject my new version binary to make it "Developer rejected" ? or should i simply add new inapp purchase products from "Manage In-App Purchases".

Comment: if i add new products then, will the products added for previous version also updated, or not,.. actually i do not want to disturb product categories of previous version and add new products for newer version at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is ready for sale, the new inapp product you added will not show in the current version. You have to create a new version, then you will be asked to select the inapp products you want to enable in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new version of your app.. thats it!